# For which rational inputs to a rational function does the output have a rational square root?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rational-functions

Given $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{Z}$, I'd like to find all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$
\sqrt{\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{dx^2+ex+f}}\in\mathbb{Q}.
$$
How would one approach such a problem?

As an explicit example, what are the solutions in the case where $(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(1,2,0,1,1,1)$?

Comment: Generally speaking, the rationality of the numerator and denominator can be treated separately, then those results can be brought together.  Since $x\in \Bbb Q$, if there are such solutions individually for both quadratics then there will be combined solutions based on an LCM of sorts...

Comment: @abiessu - The numerator and denominator need not be rational for their fraction to be rational, right?

Comment: True, giving additional solution possibilities.

Comment: Let $\sqrt{Q_1(x)/Q_2(x)}=q\in\mathbb{Q}$ so $\frac{Q_1(x)}{Q_2(x)}=q^2$ and hence you have a quadratic (or lower) $Q(x)=0$ with rational solution $x=\dots$ iff ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution due to [Boris Alexeev](http://borisalexeev.com/).

We want $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{p(x)/q(x)}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose the roots of $p$ and $q$ are all distinct, since otherwise the problem is easier. Multiplying by $q(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$, we equivalently want $\sqrt{g(x)}\in\mathbb{Q}$, where $g(x):=p(x)q(x)$. That is, we want $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$ such that $g(x)=y^2$. Since $g$ has all distinct roots by assumption, this is equivalent to finding rational points on a certain elliptic curve (see [this treatment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2909838/442087), for example). The desired solutions can therefore be obtained with the help of [Magma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1330867/442087) or [Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is by no means a complete answer, but just the straightforwrd attempt-

Let $$\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{dx^2+ex+f}=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$$
Then $$(an^2-dm^2)x^2+(bn^2-em^2)x+(cn^2-fm^2)=0$$
which implies $$x=\frac{-(bn^2-em^2)\pm\sqrt{(bn^2-em^2)^2-4(an^2-dm^2)(cn^2-fn^2)}}{2(an^2-dm^2)}$$
To make $x$ a rational number, we want the expression $$E=\{(bn^2-em^2)^2-4(an^2-dm^2)(cn^2-fn^2)\}$$ to be a perfect square.

In your example, $E$ reduces to $\{(2n^2-m^2)^2-4(n^2-m^2)m^2\}$. As we can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%204*n%5E4%2B5m%5E4-8n%5E2m%5E2%3Dx%5E2%20over%20integers), the solutions either have $m=\pm n$ or $m=0$ or $n=0$. So, chances of a non trivial solution seem to be quite thin.

But, I tweaked your explicit example a little to $(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(1,2,1,1,1,0)$. In  this case however, e have a very nice solution. We can see that
\begin{align*}
E&=(2n^2-m^2)^2-4(n^2-m^2)m^2\\
&=\{n^2+(n^2-m^2)\}^2-4(n^2-m^2)n^2\\
&=\{n^2-(n^2-m^2)\}^2\\
&=m^4
\end{align*}
So, for this particular choice of $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$, all rational values of $x$ will give a rational square root.

Answer (score 2):

The given equation is equvalent to:

$\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{dx^2+ex+f}=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$

We take:

$(a,b,c)=(1,-10,2)$

$(d,e,f)=(1,-8,-5)$

Hence we have:

$x^2-10x+2=m^2  ----(1)$

$x^2-8x-5=n^2   ---(2)$

Solving equation (1) &(2) we get:

$m^2-n^2=(7-2x)$

$(m+n)(m-n)=(7-2x)*(1)$

We take:

$m+n=(7-2x)$

$m-n=(1)$

Hence, $(m,n)=((4-x),(3-x))$

Substituting (m,n) in equations (1) & (2) we get:

$x=-7$

Hence we get:

$(m,n)=(11,10)$

$Hence (m/n)=(11/10)$